# QML TableView with dynamic entries ComboBox in dynamic colums

Tags: qt, combobox, delegates, qml, qtquick2

I am new to QML and I am evaluating using it in my current project. I had experience on WPF 2 years ago but I feel they are quiet different.

1. What I am try to do is a TableView, whose columns are dynamically generated, according to the model. This part is OK for me, it worked.
2. The second thing is using different components as delegate for different colums according to the data type inside it. I am planning to use Checkbox list and ComboBox, text field for it. In general it works as expected.
3. This is the problem since 3 days and I find no way to get it work: I hope to dynamically define the entries of ComoboBox if it's a ComboBox, I am not able to binding the function in the mode to it :(

Here are the codes:

TableEditing.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

TableView {

    Layout.fillWidth: true

    id: view
    model: myModel

    Component {
        id: columnComponent
        TableViewColumn
        {
            width: 100
        }
    }

    // <---you can ignore this editableDelegate, it's not relevant to this question
    Component {
        id: editableDelegate
        Item {

            Text {
                width: parent.width
                anchors.margins: 4
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                elide: styleData.elideMode
                text: styleData.value !== undefined ? styleData.value : ""
                color: styleData.textColor
                visible: !styleData.selected
            }
            Loader {
                id: loaderEditor
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 4
                Connections {
                    target: loaderEditor.item
                    onAccepted: {
                        if (typeof styleData.value === 'number')
                            largeModel.setProperty(styleData.row, styleData.role, Number(parseFloat(loaderEditor.item.text).toFixed(0)))
                        else
                            largeModel.setProperty(styleData.row, styleData.role, loaderEditor.item.text)
                    }
                }
                sourceComponent: styleData.selected ? editor : null
                Component {
                    id: editor
                    TextInput {
                        id: textinput
                        color: styleData.textColor
                        text: styleData.value
                        MouseArea {
                            id: mouseArea
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            hoverEnabled: true
                            onClicked: textinput.forceActiveFocus()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Read from here will be better
    Component {
        id: editableCombo
        Item {
            property var modelData : ["aa", "bb"] // <- This works
            ComboBox {
                id : combox
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Binding {
                target: combox
                property: "model"
                value: modelData
            }

        }
    }

    function getEditor(type, options) {
        switch(type) {
        case 3: return editableCombo
        default: return editableDelegate;
        }
    }

    function addCol(role, index) {
        var colType = myModel.columnType(index);
        var colOptions = myModel.optionList(index);
        var editor = getEditor(colType, colOptions);
        var cellEditor = {
            role: role,
            title: role,
            delegate: editor \\ <--------- I think here need some work, I think I need to bind colOptions to the modelData of editor, but I have tried many forms, the loader and bindings, it doesn't work

        };
        view.addColumn(columnComponent.createObject(view, cellEditor))
    }

    Connections {
        target: myModel
        onHeaderDataChanged: myModel.columnNames.forEach(addCol)
    }

}
```

This is the header of the model, columnType() gives the type of data in a column and optionList() gives the possible entries.

```
#pragma once

#include "ItemControllerBase.h"
#include "ItemPropertyDescriptor.h"
#include "Macro.h"
#include "Const.h"

namespace PROJECTNAME { namespace Controller {

class TableEditingModel : public QAbstractItemModel {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList columnNames READ columnNames CONSTANT)

public:
    TableEditingModel() = default;

    //! \brief  Déstructeur.
    ~TableEditingModel();

    Q_INVOKABLE int columnType(int columnIndex) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QStringList optionList(int columnIndex) const;

    QStringList columnNames() const;

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

    //! \brief  L'index dans QListView.
    //! \param  row     La ligne.
    //! \param  column  Le column.
    //! \return Un QModelIndex.
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;


    //! \brief  Obtiens le parent.
    //! \param  child   Le fils.
    //! \return L'index de parent.
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &) const override
    {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    //! \brief  Le numbre totale des lignes.
    //! \param  parent  Le parent.
    //! \return Le nombre totale des lignes.
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        //! \todo
        return m_controllers.size();
    }

    //! \brief  Le nombre totales des column.
    //! \param  parent  (Optional) Le parent.
    //! \return Le nombre totales des column.
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return m_controllers.size() > 0 ? m_controllers[0]->descriptor()->size() : 0;
    }

    //! \brief  Données d'un celule.
    //! \param  index   L'objet index.
    //! \param  role    Le rôle.
    //! \return La données.
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    //! \brief  Mise à jour de données.
    //! \param  index   L'index.
    //! \param  value   La valeur.
    //! \return Vrai si la modification est réussit
    bool setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    //! \brief  Renvoie le numéro de ligne d'un élément.
    //! \param  element Elément recherché
    //! \return Numéro de ligne de l'élément recherché
    int indexOf(QSharedPointer<Controller::ItemControllerBase> element) { return m_controllers.indexOf(element); }

    //! \brief  Lors l'ajoute d'une élément.
    //! \param [in,out] descriptor  Le déscripteur d'élément.
    void addElement(QSharedPointer<Controller::ItemControllerBase> element);

    //! \brief  Lors la suppression d'une élément.
    //! \param [in,out] descriptor  Le déscripteur d'élément
    void removeElement(QSharedPointer<Controller::ItemControllerBase> element);

    void refreshElement(QSharedPointer<Controller::ItemControllerBase> element);

private:
    QueryableVector<QSharedPointer<Controller::ItemControllerBase>> m_controllers;  //!< Liste des controlleurs
    QueryableVector<std::tuple<QString, Model::PropertyValueType, QStringList>> m_horizontalHeaders;    //!< Liste des titres de colonne };

} // Controller } // PROJECTNAME
```

Comment: You could use a `Loader` or a Component.createObject() within the delegate. Don't load them from files but from components, so you can modify their signals. 'Refire' custom signals with additional information (such as the index or what ever) when the originals occur.

Comment: createObject doesn't work well, they will eventually create combobox at top right of TableView. Loader seems not work with an inline component.

Comment: For the loader, you need to use `sourceComponent` for the inline components. The createObject() will just create the object. You need to set the stuff, like parent and other properties, so it will be inserted at the right position.

Comment: I am sure Loader doesn't work, I have tried it many times with sourceComponent. The problem is delegate in TableViewColumn seems be a template, not an object